# Understanding Instruments memory allocation log on iOS

Tags: ios, memory-management, instruments

I have built an iOS app that is almost done, however, I have recently experienced that it crashes after while due to "Memory pressure". So I started profiling the memory allocations in Instruments and sure, the app does use quite a lot of memory and it only seems to increase during usage.

However, relatively new to Instruments memory allocation I am not quite able to decipher where 52 % of the allocations are made, as seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

It has obviously got something to do with Core Animation, but what exactly is hard for me to determine, so I thought that some clever minds out there might know the answer to that.

### Breadcrumb:

My app uses custom segues, when moving between view controllers, where a lot of animation is taking place. Here is an example:

```
@interface AreaToKeyFiguresSegue : UIStoryboardSegue

@end

...

@implementation AreaToKeyFiguresSegue

- (void)perform
{
    [self sourceControllerOut];
}

- (void)sourceControllerOut
{
    AreaChooserViewController *sourceViewController = (AreaChooserViewController *) [self sourceViewController];
    KeyFigureViewController *destinationController = (KeyFigureViewController *) [self destinationViewController];

    double ratio = 22.0/sourceViewController.titleLabel.font.pointSize;

    sourceViewController.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:TRANSITION_DURATION delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{

        // Animate areaChooser
        sourceViewController.areaChooserScrollView.alpha = 0;
        sourceViewController.areaScrollViewVerticalSpaceConstraint.constant = -300;

        sourceViewController.backButtonVerticalConstraint.constant = 20;
        sourceViewController.backButton.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(sourceViewController.backButton.transform, ratio, ratio);
        sourceViewController.backButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor redKombitColor];

        sourceViewController.backArrowPlaceholderVerticalConstraint.constant = 14;
        sourceViewController.backArrowPlaceholder.alpha = 1;

        sourceViewController.areaLabelVerticalConstraint.constant = 50;
        sourceViewController.areaLabel.alpha = 1;

        [sourceViewController.view layoutIfNeeded];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [destinationController view]; // Make sure destionation view is initialized before animating it
        [sourceViewController.navigationController pushViewController:destinationController animated:NO]; // Push new viewController without animating it

        [self destinationControllerIn]; // Now animate destination controller
    }];
}

- (void)destinationControllerIn
{
    AreaChooserViewController *sourceViewController = (AreaChooserViewController *) [self sourceViewController];
    KeyFigureViewController *destinationController = (KeyFigureViewController *) [self destinationViewController];

    destinationController.keyFigureTableViewVerticalConstraint.constant = 600;
    destinationController.keyFigureTableView.alpha = 0.0;
    destinationController.allFavoritesSegmentedControl.alpha = 0.0;
    [destinationController.view layoutIfNeeded];
    [sourceViewController.segueProgress setHidden:YES];
} 

@end
```

And whenever a view controller is to be popped, I simply do the reverse thing:

```
- (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:TRANSITION_DURATION delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{

        [self.keyFigureTableView setAlpha:0];
        self.keyFigureTableViewVerticalConstraint.constant = 700;
        [self.allFavoritesSegmentedControl setAlpha:0];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO]; // Pop viewController without animating it
    }];
}
```

### Edit:

Most of the memory allocation takes place when pushing a view controller, even if it has already been displayed before. I.e. going from

A -> B -> C

B <- C

B -> C

where "->" = push and "<-" = pop, each "->" allocates more memory and "<-" never releases any.

### Further details

I have **no zombies** and **no leaks** according to Instruments. Static analysis also gives nothing. My app just keeps allocating memory until it finally crashes.

Around 70 % of my memory allocation happens in the following call stack, which has nothing to do with my code (inverted call tree):

[image]

Comment: Use "Mark Generation" button. Choose a point at the ruler then click Mark Generation. Then select next point to the right and click Mark Generation again, repeat. Instruments will show you difference between generations - which objects where created.

Comment: The only thing I get out of that is a bunch of hexadecimal addresses and the caller is always `vm_allocate`.

Comment: You can look at Extended Detail panel to see the stack. The image you posted is not very legible I can hardly see what is there, but if I understand correctly Core Animation allocates memory for view's backing store to draw something there. Do you have custom view with drawRect defined? What happens if you comment out layoutIfNeeded?

Comment: Extended detail basically gives the same overview af the call tree as above. If I comment out `layoutIfNeeded` there is basically no animation.

Comment: So what do you do in your layout code, can post code snippet?

Comment: In what layout code? My segues?

Comment: I meant layout code of the controller root view if you have one. You have not answered if you have custom view with drawRect: defined

Comment: Oh, sorry. No, I have no `drawRect`s anywhere. I just use Auto Layout for everything.

Comment: How are sourceViewController and destinationViewController defined as properties?

Comment: @ahwulf I've updated the code to make it more clear: It's a subclass of `UIStoryboardSegue`.

Comment: I don't use custom segues since we can only use xibs, but it looks like the custom seque might not be released when this is complete. This would mean everything it contains is building up. The problem might be outside the code you are showing. Did you try Analyze?

Comment: Yes, that gives no warnings.

Comment: If you remove the custom segues, does the problem disappear?

Comment: If I do so, it actually seems to be more willing to release some memory now and then. But it still eventually crashes due to "Memory pressure" (using around 125MB on an iPad 4th gen.).

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I debug these.

1. In Instruments, use the Allocations instrument and turn on "Record reference counts"

[image]

2. Run your app to a "steady state", including performing the operation you think is leaking a few times.
3. In Instruments, set your baseline memory level using the in/out markers.
4. Perform the operation you think is leaking a few times. (say 7)
5. In Instruments, switch to the view that shows all allocations and look for objects that have been allocated yet not deallocated the same number of times as the operation you just performed (again maybe 7 times). You'll first want to try to find an object specific to your program... So prefer `MyNetworkOperation` instances instead of generic foundation classes like `NSData`.  [image: click arrow next to class you are interested in] [image: click arrow next to an allocated object]
6. Select one of the objects that hasn't been deallocated and look at it's allocation history. You'll be able to see the call stack for every alloc/retain/release/autorelease for the object in question.. Probably one of the calls will look suspicious to you. [image: history of retain/release for selected object]

I suppose these steps apply more in a non-ARC environment. Under ARC you might be looking for something that's a retain cycle.

In general you can avoid retain cycles by making sure your strong references only go in one direction... For example, a view has strong references to it's subviews and each subview must only ever use weak references to refer to any parent view. Or perhaps your view controller has a strong reference to your view. Your view must only have a weak reference to its view controller. Another way to say this is to decide in each relationship which object "owns" the other.

Answer (score 2):

Instruments is saying that your **UIViews are leaking** (or not deallocated to be precise).

Each push will create a new `destinationController` and the `destinationController's` view will be backed by a CALayer and CALayer kills memory.

To prove that, you can just implement `dealloc` for your `destinationController` and set a breakpoint there to see if it's called.

If the dealloc is called than you can do this for other objects to find out which one. (Like `destinationController.view` )

**Why leaking?**

1, You may have retain cycles that capturing `destinationController`. It's a pain to debug, you may have to check through all your code related.

2, Every `destinationController` may be retained by some long living object. (Repeated NSTimer that are not invalidated, Singleton, RootViewController, CADisplayLink ...)

3, False cache. You cache something and try to reuse it. However, the cache logic has bugs and those objects never get reused and new objects are constantly inserted in.

Comment: I have implemented log statements the `dealloc` method in all view controllers and custom segues. The segues are deallocated immediately after push. The view controllers, however, are not. If I go A->B->C->B->A (I of course pop when going backwards) view controller B is only deallocated after a long time waiting. C is never deallocated.

Comment: This kind of memory leak is the hardest to debug. The solution I may take would be to comment out codes/files that's absolutely safe till I find which line is causing the leaking. Sometimes, even iOS can have bugs causing view controllers never released.

Answer (score 0):

Your animation mostly contains changing alpha value or colour. To reduce the animation code in custom segue, I suggest you move your animation code for destination view controller (i.e. the method `destinationControllerIn`) to `viewDidLoad:` of destination view controller.

Answer (score -2):

Check first to see if (scheme diagnostics) you have zombies turned on. Zombies means nothing is ever deleted. Given that your memory chart never goes down at all that would be my first check.

Comment: I didn't get any "Zombie messaged" dialogs, if that's what I was supposed to get?

Comment: You only get those errors if you actually send a message to a deleted object. No the issue would be that nothing is ever deleted, leading to continuously growing memory. Zombies work by not throwing anything away and turning the object into a special NSZombie class.

Comment: Yes, but I never get aware of the zombies unless I send an obj-c message to, which apparently I don't.

Comment: downvoted because this is the incorrect meaning of a zombie. A zombie is something that has been overreleased. Messaging a zombie causes a bad access. You are referring to a memory leak, where something is never fully released, leading to memory pressure.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickGoley, I was also getting confused. However, according to Instruments I have no memory leaks either.

Comment: Having Zombies on while doing testing with instruments for memory issues is something I've answered many times already. It's easy to do by accident and gives the same pattern in memory usage. It's still a zombie whether you message it or not. In this case it is not the problem but it's still worth checking for.

Comment: It is correct that having zombies turned on can cause what looks like leaks. (Zombies are never deallocated.) However I wouldn't look at that first when looking for a memory leak.

Comment: "A zombie is something that has been overreleased" - surely it should be "A zombie is a placeholder object for something that has been deallcoated" (i.e. no negative ref counts involved).