# Setting rightBarButtonItem prohibiting UIViewController from being deallocated

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I've spent all day debugging why my `UIViewController` isn't getting deallocated after being dismissed, and I've narrowed it down to the fact that I'm setting a rightBarButtonItem. My project is using ARC.

In my `appDelegate`, I present a 'welcome' screen if the user hasn't signed in:

```
// AppDelegate.m
WelcomeViewController *welcome = [[WelcomeViewController alloc] initWithContext:AuthenticationPresentationContextSplash];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:welcome];
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:nav animated:false completion:nil];
```

Then, when a user signs in or taps the rightBarButtonItem, I dismiss the viewController:

```
// WelcomeViewController.m
- (IBAction)onSkipOrCancel
{
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
}
```

I've confirmed that in both `AppDelegate` and `WelcomeViewController`, self.window.rootViewController and self.presentingViewController refer to the exact same instance of the same UIViewController.

Oddly enough, after all day of working on this, I figured out the problem is in this code:

```
// also in WelcomeViewController.m
- (void)configureRightBarButtonItem
{
    UIBarButtonItem *rightItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Skip"
                                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                 target:self
                                                                 action:@selector(onSkipOrCancel)];

    // if i comment this out, when onSkipOrCancel runs and the presentingViewController
    // is sent dismissViewController, WelcomeViewController will successfully get deallocated
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightItem;
}
```

Seems as though a strong reference to WelcomeViewController is created while setting `rightBarButtonItem`. Why is that and how do I work around it?

Comment: Have you used the Allocations tool in Instruments to look at what is holding the reference to the view controller? You may see some other unexpected references that might be side effects of setting the button.

Comment: You may also want to change your `onSkipOrCancel` method to be: `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: unfortunately changing it to [self dismissViewControllerAnimated] didn't fix the problem.

Comment: i haven't used the Allocations tool yet because i'm not quite sure how to find that type of information (figure out who else is holding a reference to the view controller). Are you able to provide some steps to help me out?

Comment: The following should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20471973/understanding-instruments-memory-allocation-log-on-ios/20647234#20647234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an aggravating day, it turns out it was a bug in Taplytics v1.2.24. The bug was fixed in 1.2.32.

They have a category on UIBarButtonItem where they do some method swizzling, and were holding a strong reference to the target of the rightBarButtonItem (which was my viewController). That in turn was preventing my UIViewController from deallocating.

Comment: Ouch. That's a tough one.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
// also in WelcomeViewController.m
- (void)configureRightBarButtonItem
{
    UIBarButtonItem *rightItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Skip"
                                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                 target:self
                                                                 action:@selector(onSkipOrCancel)];

    // if i comment this out, when onSkipOrCancel runs and the presentingViewController
    // is sent dismissViewController, WelcomeViewController will successfully get deallocated
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightItem;
    [rightItem release];//whenever we alloc we should release it too!
}
```

Comment: i should have added I'm using ARC.